# How to get off moisturizing soap quickly

Tags: cleaning, home, personal-care, bathroom, washing

When I wash my hands with liquid hand soap (Dial, Softsoap or any other brand), it doesn't get off quickly. I believe thats because of the moisturizing element (to prevent drying hands). If you have ever used Dove, you know what I am talking about.

I hate it so much. How do I get available soaps to get off quickly? Can I use/do anything which will wash off the soap quickly? I can deal with drying hands but I need a soap that gets off quickly. Should I use any other brands?

Comment: This is a shopping request, not a lifehack.

Comment: Either use another brand, or spend longer rinsing and rubbing with plain water afterwards. In other words, wash your hands a second time, with plain water.

Comment: Everything you list as a soap is a detergent - different. Look for (or make - it's not hard) soap. Look up what is in soap and then start your shopping. **Lifehack** Use alcohol based hand sanitizer instead of liquid hand washing detergent.

Comment: Soap sold as dishwashing liquid is harsher on skin but doesn't leave the film you object to that 'skin safe' hand washing soaps do.

Comment: Found it. This hand soap is the best. Gets off quickly: https://www.samsclub.com/p/mm-antibac-hand-soap-1-gallon/prod20640582